# How to get unbroken table border with apache FOP

Tags: java, xslt, apache-fop

I'm trying to create a simple Table with solid borders using apache FOP, but the corners are disjoint. How can I get the table borders completely solid?

This is what the top left-hand Table Cell looks like, magnified 64 times:

[image: Top left-hand Table Cell, magnified 64 times]

Here's my Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"  version="3.0">
    <xsl:template match="XpathNode">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master  master-name="singlePage"  page-width="297mm"  page-height="210mm">
                    <fo:region-body  margin-left="12.69mm"  margin-top="17.70mm" />
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence  master-reference="singlePage">
                <fo:flow  flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:table>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="2mm"/>
                        <fo:table-column column-width="7mm"/>
                        <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row height="2mm">
                                <fo:table-cell border="0.51mm solid"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border="0.51mm solid"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-row height="4mm">
                                <fo:table-cell border="0.51mm solid"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell border="0.51mm solid"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                        </fo:table-body>
                    </fo:table>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Many XSL FO formatters use polygons (not lines) for borders. This is (in fact) the exact proper way to do it. Can you get pixel differences because of this? Yes. But not nearly as much as you do with formatters that use lines where one overlaps another. Consider how would one truly represent a border that is red on the top but black on the sides ... should the sides overlap the top or should the top overlap the sides ... or should it be a polygon. So, you are only visually seeing (magnified 64 times which is way above the resolution of the PDF itself) what happens. There is no answer.

Comment: I think it should be solid. That's how it is in tables in HTML, MS Office & Libre Office, but more importantly, I have a Form dictated by a german Government Agency that must be rendered exactly & you don't mess with german Government Agencies.  I've created something in SVG that does the trick. Not sure if I can inline that in my Stylesheet...

Comment: You must mean magnified 6400%. I will post a no answer ... answer just to prove out some things.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to think HTML is acceptable, let see what happens with HTML. Here is a sample directly from the spec, formatted save the HTML to PDF.

As you can see, the top border is square but the side borders are polygons. The top border is not aligned perfectly and in fact overlaps to the left and right of the side borders.

And that is apparent at just about all zoom levels, this is only 1200% which is much less than the 6400%.

[image]

Word does things a bit different, but that also has issues. See this at only 200% zoom, you can clearly see the overlap of the red and the black. You possibly don't think this exists because you have all black border.

[image]

As you stated, possibly SVG which would likely map to a rectangle in PDF could be a solution. You can use background-image and use base64 encoded SVG inside it or use fo:instream-foreign-object to inline it (but that would depend on whether you want content inside it.

An alternative option would be a black background behind a white <smaller) background, not using any borders. Setting proper padding could yield two rectangles, one behind the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Java's got a single-pixel bug like that in one of the borders, EtchedBorder if I remember rightly. I did report it about 15 years ago. With a solution! Never did get fixed...

Anyway, I'm getting close now with an SVG & `fo:instream-foreign-object`. A few more iterations needed, but looks like I've got it cornered.

For what it's worth, here's an excerpt:

```
<fo:block-container position="absolute">
    <fo:block>
        <fo:instream-foreign-object xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" content-width="273mm">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1184" height="773" viewBox="0 0 1184 773">
                <g style="fill-opacity:0;stroke-width:3;stroke:black">
                    <rect x="2"    y="2"   width="254"  height="99"/>
                    <rect x="256"  y="2"   width="485"  height="99"/>
                    <rect x="741"  y="2"   width="407"  height="99"/>
                    <rect x="1148" y="2"   width="35"   height="770"/>
                    <rect x="2"    y="101" width="254"  height="165"/>
                    <rect x="256"  y="101" width="485"  height="165"/>
                    <rect x="741"  y="101" width="407"  height="165"/>
                    <rect x="2"    y="266" width="1146" height="341"/>
                    <rect x="2"    y="607" width="254"  height="165"/>
                    <rect x="256"  y="607" width="485"  height="165"/>
                    <rect x="741"  y="607" width="407"  height="165"/>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </fo:instream-foreign-object>
    </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

Comment: Nice solution for one cell. Good luck with variable sized content.

Comment: Yeah, the whole Form needs to be absolute so the government agency can OCR the PDF we send them via ftp!! (I did ask them if they had a more modern solution, but they answered "We are a government agency: that IS modern."  But at least the rest is only Text...

Comment: Then why not use a blank government provided PDF form and stamp the text on top, using the PDF as a background? Doesn't seem like you need the borders in the FO

Comment: For the "electronic" reporting they only provide an already filled-out example form & recommend you print it out together with your attempt & then hold them up against the light to make sure all fields align EXACTLY.  Seriously!!  This is germany mate! So I'm busy absolutely positioning every field.  Fortunately it is a fairly small A5 form with not too many fields. Nearly done now...